# Ruby on rails 6, how manage multiply omniauth provider when using devise gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth, ruby-on-rails-6

everybody, I'm doing one application now and I'm a little confused, I'd appreciate your help. For authentication, I chose Devise gem and oauth2 for social logins.

The problem I can't solve is that I can register either by mail or using some social login. I am trying to make it possible for a one user can login using any of the available social logins (Providers) and email. And if, for example, a user has already been registered by mail, allow him to login through the social login of the selected system (provider).

Also in the future, if this task is solved, I plan to give an opportunity to add or remove the social network when the user edits the information about himself (if it is important, in the current context).

My code at the moment:

*routes.rb*

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'pages#home'
  devise_for :users, controllers: { omniauth_callbacks: 'users/omniauth_callbacks' }
end
```

*user.rb*

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable,
         :confirmable, :omniauthable, omniauth_providers: %i[github google_oauth2 facebook twitter linkedin gitlab]

  def self.from_omniauth(auth)
      where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
        user.email = auth.info.email
        user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0, 20]
        user.name = auth.info.name
        user.image = auth.info.image
        user.skip_confirmation!
      end
    end

    def self.new_with_session(params, session)
      super.tap do |user|
        if data = session["devise.github"] && session["devise.github_data"]["extra"]["raw_info"]
          user.email = data["email"] if user.email.blank?
        end
        if data = session["devise.google_oauth2"] && session["devise.google_oauth2_data"]["extra"]["raw_info"]
          user.email = data["email"] if user.email.blank?
        end
        if data = session["devise.facebook"] && session["devise.facebook_data"]["extra"]["raw_info"]
          user.email = data["email"] if user.email.blank?
        end
        if data = session["devise.twitter"] && session["devise.twitter_data"]["extra"]["raw_info"]
          user.email = data["email"] if user.email.blank?
        end
        if data = session["devise.linkedin"] && session["devise.linkedin_data"]["extra"]["raw_info"]
          user.email = data["email"] if user.email.blank?
        end
        if data = session["devise.gitlab"] && session["devise.gitlab_data"]["extra"]["raw_info"]
          user.email = data["email"] if user.email.blank?
        end
      end
    end
end
```

*omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb*

```
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  def github
    @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])
    if @user.persisted?
      sign_in_and_redirect @user, event: :authentication
      set_flash_message(:notice, :success, kind: "Github") if is_navigational_format?
    else
      session["devise.github_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url, alert: @user.errors.full_messages.join("\n")
    end
  end

  def google_oauth2
    @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env['omniauth.auth'])

    if @user.persisted?
      sign_in_and_redirect @user, event: :authentication
      set_flash_message(:notice, :success, kind: "Google") if is_navigational_format?
    else
      session['devise.google_data'] = request.env['omniauth.auth'].except(:extra)
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url, alert: @user.errors.full_messages.join("\n")
    end
  end

  def facebook
    @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env['omniauth.auth'])

    if @user.persisted?
      sign_in_and_redirect @user, event: :authentication
      set_flash_message(:notice, :success, kind: "Facebook") if is_navigational_format?
    else
      session['devise.facebook_data'] = request.env['omniauth.auth'].except(:extra)
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url, alert: @user.errors.full_messages.join("\n")
    end
  end

  def twitter
    @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env['omniauth.auth'])

    if @user.persisted?
      sign_in_and_redirect @user, event: :authentication
      set_flash_message(:notice, :success, kind: "Twitter") if is_navigational_format?
    else
      session['devise.twitter_data'] = request.env['omniauth.auth'].except(:extra)
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url, alert: @user.errors.full_messages.join("\n")
    end
  end

  def linkedin
    @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env['omniauth.auth'])

    if @user.persisted?
      sign_in_and_redirect @user, event: :authentication
      set_flash_message(:notice, :success, kind: "Linkedin") if is_navigational_format?
    else
      session['devise.linkedin_data'] = request.env['omniauth.auth'].except(:extra)
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url, alert: @user.errors.full_messages.join("\n")
    end
  end

  def gitlab
    @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])
    if @user.persisted?
      sign_in_and_redirect @user, event: :authentication
      set_flash_message(:notice, :success, kind: "Gitlab") if is_navigational_format?
    else
      session["devise.gitlab_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url, alert: @user.errors.full_messages.join("\n")
    end
  end

  def failure
    flash[:error] = 'There was a problem signing you in. Please register or try signing in later.'
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

*My Gemfile*

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.7.1'

gem 'rails', '~> 6.0.3', '>= 6.0.3.1'
gem 'pg', '>= 0.18', '< 2.0'
gem 'puma', '~> 4.1'
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 6'
gem 'webpacker', '~> 4.0'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.7'
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.4.2', require: false

gem 'devise'
gem 'omniauth-github'
gem 'omniauth-gitlab'
gem 'omniauth-twitter'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
gem 'omniauth-google-oauth2'
gem 'omniauth-linkedin-oauth2'
gem 'activerecord-session_store'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'dotenv-rails'
  gem 'letter_opener'
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.2'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

*schema.rb*

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2020_06_04_090555) do

  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "sessions", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "session_id", null: false
    t.text "data"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["session_id"], name: "index_sessions_on_session_id", unique: true
    t.index ["updated_at"], name: "index_sessions_on_updated_at"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.string "confirmation_token"
    t.datetime "confirmed_at"
    t.datetime "confirmation_sent_at"
    t.string "unconfirmed_email"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.string "name"
    t.string "image"
    t.string "provider"
    t.string "uid"
    t.index ["confirmation_token"], name: "index_users_on_confirmation_token", unique: true
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end

end
```

Comment: To understand the question correctly, if a user signs up with their email and password (User1) and at a later stage use a oauth provider to login with the same email, they should login as the same user (User1)?

Comment: Your current schema checks directly for the `uid` and `provider` stored on the user model. To allow multiple providers, you will have to implement a separate model to store the `uid`s and `provider`s everytime a user signs up through oauth and have that mapped to the user's record. Its mentioned here very well https://github.com/omniauth/omniauth/wiki/Managing-Multiple-Providers

Comment: @MoizMansur thank you for the answer, yes, that's right. I found this solution, but did not understand how to apply it in the context of using Devise as an authentication tool and using activerecord-session_store.